# Strange behavior of GO command within a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I ran the following:

```
CREATE TABLE t1  
    (a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);  
CREATE TABLE t2  
    (a INT NOT NULL REFERENCES t1(a));  

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);  
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3);  
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4);  
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (6);  
GO
```

and after that I run this:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON; 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1)

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2) -- Foreign key error, entire transaction rolled back

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

then anything is ok; the transaction is rolled back because we don't have value 2 in t1 and as a result table t2 is empty

But if I add a `GO` command in the middle of this transaction then the transaction is not rolled back and number 3 is inserted into table t2. Here is the code:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON; 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1)

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2) -- Foreign key error.  

GO  --this command breaks the transaction

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I know that `GO` is not a sql statement but rather a SQL Server Management Studio utility command that is not actually sent to the SQL server.

So, why after running the last code snippet above (the one that includes GO command) I can see number 3 in table t2

I used SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: This is definitely in-line with the expected behavior.  It may be your misunderstanding of how `GO` works.  Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 to understand more on `batch`

Comment: Point: `GO` does ***not*** break a transaction.  Transactions are session-level artifacts, not batch-level.  `GO` in SSMS breaks a batch, not a session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When [`SET XACT_ABORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188792.aspx) is `ON`, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
>   run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

The transaction opened in the first batch *does* get automatically rolled back on error.

Then SSMS sees there is another batch to process and fires off

```
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

As the first transaction is now closed this starts a new auto commit transaction. And at the end there is an unexpected `COMMIT TRANSACTION` so that raises an error.

You can alter the second batch to check if the transaction in the first batch was unceremoniously rolled back.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON; 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1)

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2) -- Foreign key error.  

GO 

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Transaction closed',16,1);
    RETURN;
    END

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Or you can turn on SQLCMD mode and use

```
:on error exit
```

If you want no further batches to be processed after an error.

[image]

Comment: I'm inline with this answer but OP says he can see `2` in table after GO instead of getting rolled back; I was little confused whether OP was sure about the question though :)

Comment: Spot on, as always.

Comment: Yes, I can see number 2 in table t2. This is the issue. You can just copy the code/paste code and try.

Comment: @Christian - I have copied and pasted and definitely see 3. Check again. And make sure that the table is empty before you start.

Comment: So, the problem is why I can see number 3.

Comment: That's explained in my answer. The first tran is rolled back because you request that with `XACT_ABORT` and then a new one starts.

Comment: There's no setting or condition that should allow (2) to be put in that table if the FK constraint is raising an error on it.  The only explanation I can think of for that is that it was in there previously.

Comment: But shouldn't the scope for XACT_ABORT ON be between BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION so that it rolls back anything in-between? Why should the transaction terminate on error. Isn't the purpose of XACT_ABORT ON that it has to roll back anything in-between?

Comment: @Christian - SQL Server doesn't know anything about future batches that you are going to submit. SSMS only submits the batch `BEGIN TRANSACTION INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1);INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2) ;` initially. That encounters an error and the transaction is rolled back due to your `XACT_ABORT` setting. And then SSMS submits a second batch **after the first transaction is already dead** You could also alter that to check `@@trancount` is 1 as expected.

Comment: Ok. So I understand. And why SQL Server accepts a batch that has BEGIN TRANSACTION without a matching COMMIT TRANSACTION?? Why doesn't it give an error on such a batch?

Comment: @Christian - There are legitimate circumstances where you want to keep a transaction open, check results manually with adhoc queries and then commit when ready.

Comment: @MartinSmith I had changed SSMS to SQL Server in the meantime...great help from you, now anything makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Christian Most statements in T-SQL like `BEGIN..END` and `BEGIN TRY..END TRY`, etc. are *structural*.  That is, they are not executable, but rather form code structures, so to be compiled a `BEGIN` must have an `END`.  However `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` (and `ROLLBACK`) are *not* structural, rather they are actually *executable* statements that change the current session state. This is why there is no `END TRANSACTION`, and why the `COMMIT` doesn't have to exist when the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is compiled and thus how a transaction can be a session-level state/entity.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Very informative. Thanks for explaining why it works like that at the core. Many thanks!